# Is there any simple example for volumetric data except from physics and medicine?

Tags: datasets, applications

Recently I heard about the term volumetric data. The definition for volumetric data is as follows

#1: [Definition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/volumetric-data)

> Volumetric data is typically a set S of samples $(x, y, z, v)$,
> representing the value v of some property of the data, at a 3D
> location $(x, y, z)$. If the value is simply a 0 or a 1, with a value
> of 0 indicating background and a value of 1 indicating the object,
> then the data is referred to as binary data. The data may instead be
> multivalued, with the value representing some measurable property of
> the data, including, for example, color, density, heat, or pressure.

#2: [Some more details](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/volumetric-dataset)

> A volumetric dataset consists of information at sample locations in
> some space. The information may be a scalar (such as density in a
> computed tomography (CT) scan), a vector (such as velocity in a flow
> field), or a higher-order tensor (such as energy, density, and
> momentum in computational fluid dynamics (CFD)). The space is usually
> 3D, consisting of either three spatial dimensions or another
> combination of spatial and frequency dimensions.

In simple words, I can say that volumetric data is nothing but a three-dimensional collection of tensors.

The articles linked above contain some examples of volumetric data in the medical (and probably physics) domain.

Are there any other simple real-world examples for volumetric data other than the medical and physics domain and physics?

Comment: "Physics" is quite broad... That eliminates several engineering applications I can think of. However, you mention medicine, where it's mostly used by biophysicists, so by physics, do you mean pure/theoretical physics?

Comment: @Avatrin Yeah, I do mean pure/theoretical physics.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a system is being modelled in three dimensions, you can be sure that tensors either can or are being used. Most of the systems I can think of are either simulated volumetric data, or a combination of real measurements and interpolated values.

### CAD and BIM

Computer-Aided Design, or CAD, if quite commonly used in engineering. It's quite natural that, if they are modelling a mechanical system, that they need information regarding the materials they are considering to use to make the device; A little bit of googling showed that [Autodesks Inventor computes inertia tensors](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/What-are-differences-between-Inertia-Tensor-and-Area-Moments-of-Inertia-with-respect-to-principal-Axes-in-Inventor-Region-Properties.html) and their [mechanical simulation software computes stress tensors](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/SimMech-UsersGuide/files/GUID-E2ADA0DB-37FE-487E-ABFC-02A7286DC6F6-htm.html).

BIM is essentially CAD for the construction industry, but again, a lot of the same kind of information regarding the materials used is needed; Else, the building may collapse.

### Geology

Modelling the stability of soil to construct a skyscraper may require 3D data. There is an [old question at gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15876/3d-subsurface-modelling) discussing software used to model geological systems. Of those, [this one](https://www.aquaveo.com/software/gms-groundwater-modeling-system-introduction) and [this other one](http://www.petrosys.com.au/products-services/surface-modeling-volumetrics/) still seems to be up.

### Meteorology

Most meteorological data, to the best of my knowledge, is two-dimensional. However, weather radar can be used to extract 3D data with information about precipitation and motion.